# Updating media items using Sitecore Powershell Extensions

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm looking for a way I can bulk update media items currently with Sitecore Powershell, but happy to here of any other suggestions.

I need a way of swapping out the blob value of a Sitecore media item for another media item. Is this even possible with Sitecore Powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With 4.0 updated this week there will be a great way to do this using the new Remoting module functionality that Michael added as part of [this issue](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/528). If you cannot hang on for a few more days feel free to contact me directly and I can pass the release binaries earlier.

I wouldn't honestly send remote files to server with the previous implementations as the files were going through serious serialization/deserialization in the process.

However if your files are already on the server there is another way that ingests files from the server file system into the media library that you can check out [in a gist I've written a while back here](https://gist.github.com/AdamNaj/ad2d059c618df2fc4c03).

Comment: Thanks, Adam. That's really helpful. I'll give your gist a try.